# SecurityException while creating cookie at silverlight 4 application

Tags: security, cookies, silverlight-4.0

I have a problem with WebRequest in Silverlight 4. In method ReadCallback at  `request.EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;`

I've got an error about security. I don't know what is a source of this problem. I've added to DownloadUpload.Web(asp.net 4) project 2 files : clientaccesspolicy.xml, and crossdomain.xml as in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955(v=vs.95).aspx
and I still have this error.

This is a class at silverlight application:

```
public class CookieSample
{
    private const string ServerPath = "http://localhost:8975/";
    private const string CookieService = "CookieService.ashx";

    public static void SendCookie()
    {
        WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create(ServerPath + CookieService);

        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri(ServerPath),
            new Cookie("mycookie", "Hello"));
        request.BeginGetResponse(ReadCallback, request);
    }

    private static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        var response = request.EndGetResponse(result)
            as HttpWebResponse;//here I get error
        var stringValue = response.Cookies["mycookie"].Value;
    }
}
```

This is a class at DownloadUpload.Web project named CookieService.ashx.cs

```
public class CookieService : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var cookie = context.Request.Cookies["mycookie"];

            cookie.Value += " success";

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
System.Security.SecurityException was unhandled by user code
  Message=""
  StackTrace:
       w System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state)
       w System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       w DownloadUpload.Helpers.CookieSample.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
       w System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassd.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__b(Object state2)
       w System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
       w System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       w System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
       w System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       w System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
  InnerException: System.Security.SecurityException
       Message=Security error.
       StackTrace:
            w System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            w System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
            w System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__1(Object sendState)
       InnerException:
```

What's wrong with this code?

I've got it from Silverlight 4 in Action book.

Here are paths of files are being used:

C:\Users\Damian\Downloads\DownloadUpload\DownloadUpload.Web\CookieService.ashx.cs
C:\Users\Damian\Downloads\DownloadUpload\DownloadUpload.Web\clientaccesspolicy.xml
C:\Users\Damian\Downloads\DownloadUpload\DownloadUpload\Helpers\CookieSample.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have used the exact copy of the clientaccesspolicy.xml from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), you might want to allow all http-request-headers by specifying a wildcard. I don't think you are using a standard SOAP action call.

```
  <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
```

Comment: I've modified clientaccesspolicy.xml  and it works. I've marked your answer as helpful. Could me explain from what you know that I'm not using Soap action call? Even some article would be great